# Creating a hyperlink containing variables

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I'm still pretty new to VBA but i'm trying to get a macro to add a hyperlink based on information stored in a spreadsheet.

So, for example, the link would look something like this (where by the variable parts of the links are listed as VARIABLE:

```
www.example.com/VARIABLE1&Diff=300&Start=0000VARIABLE2&End=2359VARIABLE3
```

I have already worked out these variables in my excel spreadsheet using a previous macro:

VARIABLE1: This variable is stored in column H, it is an individual variable for each row.

VARIABLE2: This variable is stored in Q8. this is the same for each row, the number is worked out in a previous macro but is the same for every row in the document

VARIABLE3: This variable is stored in R8. this is the same for each row, the number is worked out in a previous macro but is the same for every row in the document

So far i have the following code, but i'm having no luck. It either includes the variable name as text inside the formula in excel, rather than what is stored in the variable or it doesn't work at all. I've tried various ways but no luck:

```
Dim Variable2 As Long

Dim Variable3 As Long

Variable2 = range("Q8").Value

Variable3 = range("R8").Value

range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(""https://www.example.com"" & RC[3] & ""&Diff=300&Start=0000"" & Variable2 & ""&End=2359"" & Variable 3)"
```

This formula then needs to be copied down all the way down column 'E' to the last row of data to create a hyperlink for each row of the spreadsheet.

Any help / guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a few quotation marks. Try this:

```
Sub testy()

Dim variable1, variable2, variable3 As Long

variable2 = range("Q8").Value

variable3 = range("R8").Value

Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(""www.example.com/""&RC[3]&""Diff=300&Start=" & variable2 & "&End=2359" & variable3 & """)"

 End Sub
```

If that doesn't work, it might have to do  with your data type you're storing in Variable1, 2 and 3 - if they are not used in any other calculation other than to build this string, I recommend setting them as **String** instead of **Long**.

---

Edit: Also, regarding your need to populate the entire column E with this formula, this will work:

```
Sub testy2()

Dim i, n, variable2, variable3 As Long

variable2 = Range("Q8").Value

variable3 = Range("R8").Value

n = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Change "A" with whichever column contains your data records

For i = 2 To n
Range("E" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(""www.example.com/""&RC[3]&""Diff=300&Start=" & variable2 & "&End=2359" & variable3 & """)"
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah you absolute hero, thanks so much for the help. Works perfectly. Thanks again!